# Setting WPF Button enabled based on multiple control validation errors

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I have a button that I want to be enabled only if all the editable controls are validated. I have been able to do this for a single control, and can add more. However, I'd like to have it be covered for all editable controls. Is this possible?

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding OnRequestSavePreferences}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,286,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=(Validation.HasError), ElementName=checkIntervalMs}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Is adding more Conditions to the `MultiDataTrigger` not suitable for you?

Comment: I'm concerned about maintenance, and remembering to update the MultiDataTrigger. I'm hoping there's a way to have the condition bound to validation errors on any control. I would think that's a fairly standard thing to do.. the form entry is invalid if any field is invalid.